# Как получить данные из Discord Embed discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Хочу достать данные из Embed сообщения (имя автора и описание). Как это сделать? Пробовал через код найденный где-то в интернете, выдает ошибку. Для примера пусть строчки сохранятся в переменную emb

```
async def on_message(message):
    msg_id = message.id
    emb = discord.Embed(await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)) 
    print(emb)
```

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
emb = await channel.fetch_message(1040191266908024893)
print(f"{emb.embeds[0].title=}\n"
f"{emb.embeds[0].description=}\n"
f"{emb.embeds[0].footer.text=}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ты типо хочешь вывести в консоль discord.Embed? не знаю как ты себе это представляешь. Либо ты не должен использовать discord.Embed, либо ты должен отправить это в канал дискорда. Кстати , ошибка из-за того что ты не использовал аргументы discord.Embed, ты должен поместить

```
await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
```

в переменную и передать ее в description discord.Embed, или просто вывести в консоль через print, без discord.Embed.

Comment: У меня в дискорд приходит сообщение по типу этого https://prnt.sc/rQ0D2SW4v2Hu  и я хочу достать из него автора и описание, хочу чтобы они сохранились в переменную чтобы дальше с ними работать (Embed отправляет не мой вебхук, поэтому все так сложно)